# How to automatizate the deletion process of edges in a igraph object through a condition?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a directed graph `g`. A pair of nodes  can be connected by more that one edge. I need to leave only one edge. The edge's direction does not matter.

```
library(igraph)

g1 <- graph.formula( A ++ B ++ C, E ++ B ++ D, A -+ E, E -+ C, C -+ D, D -+ A )
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(g1, edge.curved = TRUE)
```

The list of edges is:

```
edges <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(g1));
edges <- edges[order(edges$V1, edges$V2), ]
edges 

#   V1 V2
#1   A  B
#2   A  E
#3   B  A # delete
#4   B  C # delete
#6   B  D # delete
#5   B  E # delete
#7   C  B
#8   C  D
#11  D  A
#12  D  B
#9   E  B
#10  E  C
```

My attempt is:

```
g2 <- delete_edges(g1, c("B|A", "B|E", "B|C", "B|D"))
plot(as.undirected(g2))
```

**Question.**  How to automatizate the deletion process through a condition?

[image]

Comment: Does `simplify`give you the desired output?

Comment: @Nick I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do. Do you want to turn a *directed* graph into an *undirected* graph?

Comment: @bennutzer, a graph does not have loops and multiedge.